# changes made to playback devices crashes program audio. how do i bring back the sound without restarting the programs?

Tags: windows-7, audio

if i go to playback devices, rightclick the device, then click properties

[image: http://prntscr.com/9cef9m]

then change something like something in enhancements

[image: http://prntscr.com/9cefpa]

when i click apply, sound stops working for all programs playing sound. i assume this is unavoidable. but how to  i then bring back the sound without having to restart the programs? this is especialy frustrating for large games that take a long time to load up like GTA5 or minecraft with alot of mods installed

Answer (score 0):

Try [AudioSwitcher](http://audioswit.ch/er)

It allows you to switch outputs on the fly - hopefully switching to the Realtek then back to the Logitech will restore the sound, or act least test whether sound then works for one output but not another; which would likely be a driver issue on that one device.